# Input showing placeholder instead of value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am having trouble to set the input to show the placeholder instead of displaying the value from state.

```
  const initialState = [
    {
      name: "Chris",
      age: 0,
      height: 0,
      weight: 0,
    },
  ];

const [infoValue, setInfoValue] = useState(initialState)

    <div>
     <input type="number" placeholder={0} value={infoValue.age} onClick={} onChange={} />
    </div>
```

Is there something I can do in onChange or onClick where the user can just enter their values without having to delete the initial 0 first?

Comment: The reason why is because infoValue.age is 0 at the beginning, you need to put an empty string in order to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The initial value is 0, so it will show up in the field. Empty string might work.

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="0" value="" />
```

The above snippet was for demo, you just need to change the value of `age` property in your code.

```
 const initialState = [
    {
      name: "Chris",
      age: '',
      height: 0,
      weight: 0,
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer if you want the age in the state to start with 0.

```
     const initialState = [
    {
      name: "Chris",
      age: 0,
      height: 0,
      weight: 0,
    },
  ];

const [infoValue, setInfoValue] = useState(initialState)

    <div>
     <input type="number" placeholder={0} value={infoValue.age||''} onClick={} onChange={} />
    </div>
```

Comment: this worked perfectly Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer if this worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value like the way you we're doing, but to change as the user types a new age you could do this:

```
  const initialState = {
  name: "Chris",
  age: 0,
  height: 0,
  weight: 0,
  },
```

;

const [infoValue, setInfoValue] = useState(initialState)

```
<div>
 <input type="number" placeholder={0} value={infoValue.age} onChange={(e) => setInfoValue({...infoValue, age: e.target.value )} />
</div>
```